# Reading CSV with list valued columns in rust

Tags: csv, serialization, rust, deserialization

I'm trying to use `csv` and `serde` to read a mixed-delimiter csv-type file in rust, but I'm having a hard time seeing how to use these libraries to accomplish it. Each line looks roughly like:
`value1|value2|subvalue1,subvalue2,subvalue3|value4`

and would de-serialize to a struct that looks like:

```
struct Line {
    value1:u64,
    value2:u64,
    value3:Vec<u64>,
    value4:u64,
}
```

Any guidance on how to tell the library that there are two different delimiters and that one of the columns has this nested structure?

Comment: The csv library is for parsing csv. You're asking to parse csv and some other format (possibly csv) within a field. The second step is something you need to handle yourself, possibly by implementing Deserialize yourself. The library won't do it for you.

Comment: Other libraries can help, however.  You might, for example, consider something like [`serde_with::StringWithSeparator`](https://docs.rs/serde_with/1.9.1/serde_with/struct.StringWithSeparator.html).

Comment: You can also use `serde(deserialize_with)` to provide your own deserialisation function for that specific field. `serde_with` has tons of nice goodies though, so getting familiar with it is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm still a beginner in Rust so I can't guarantee that this is good at all- I suspect it could be done more efficiently, but I do have a solution that works-

```
use csv::{ReaderBuilder};
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer};
use serde::de::Error;
use std::error::Error as StdError;


#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct ListType {
    values: Vec<u8>,
}

fn deserialize_list<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<ListType , D::Error>
where D: Deserializer<'de> {
    let buf: &str = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;

    let mut rdr = ReaderBuilder::new()
        .delimiter(b',')
        .has_headers(false)
        .from_reader(buf.as_bytes());
    
    let mut iter = rdr.deserialize();

    if let Some(result) = iter.next() {
        let record: ListType = result.map_err(D::Error::custom)?;
                
        return Ok(record)
    } else {
        return Err("error").map_err(D::Error::custom)
    }
}

struct Line {
    value1:u64,
    value2:u64,
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_list")]
    value3:ListType,
    value4:u64,
}

fn read_line(line: &str) -> Result<Line, Box<dyn StdError>> {
    let mut rdr = ReaderBuilder::new()
        .delimiter(b'|')
        .from_reader(line.as_bytes());
    
    let mut iter = rdr.deserialize();

    if let Some(result) = iter.next() {
        let record: Line = result?;
        return Ok(Line)
    } else {
        return Err(From::from("error"));
    }
}
```

[EDIT]

I found that the above solution was intolerably slow, but I was able to make performance acceptable by simply manually deserializing the nested type into a fixed size array by-

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct ListType {
    values: [Option<u8>; 8],
}

fn deserialize_farray<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<ListType, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let buf: &str = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;

    let mut split = buf.split(",");

    let mut dest: CondList = CondList {
        values: [None; 8],
    };

    let mut ind: usize = 0;

    for tok in split {
        if tok == "" {
            break;
        }

        match tok.parse::<u8>() {
            Ok(val) => {
                dest.values[ind] = Some(val);
            }
            Err(e) => {
                return Err(e).map_err(D::Error::custom);
            }
        }

        ind += 1;
    }

    return Ok(dest);
}
```